# How to write the condition in select column's in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Select statement like

```
select AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(Day,CreatedDate,FirstTouchDate) AS BIGINT) else null end) AS avgdaystofirstattempt,
       AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(Day,CreatedDate,Completeddate) AS BIGINT)) AS AvgDaystoComplete
from Table1
```

how can i write the  condition for column avgdaystofirstattempt - FirstTouchdate not like '%1900%' in the select itself but not in where clause.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't.  The condition has the function `avg()` which is not allowed in the `where` clause.  It is allowed in the `having` clause.  Instead of just showing a query that doesn't work, why not edit the question and include sample data and desired results?

Comment: I think what he's trying to do is to selectively include only certain rows in the `avg` statement, not exclude them from the query entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can selectively include data in an aggregate statement by using `CASE`. It's not really clear from your question, but I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(
             CASE 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CreatedDate,FirstTouchDate) < 1900 THEN NULL
               ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(Day,CreatedDate,FirstTouchDate) AS BIGINT)
               END
           ) AS avgdaystofirstattempt,
       AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(Day,CreatedDate,Completeddate) AS BIGINT)) AS AvgDaystoComplete
FROM Table1
```